# how to copy link row from multiple excel sheets to a master sheet (same work book)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from M, T, W, T, F to a Weekly sheet. I am using the following code which is creating a new master sheet called "Weekly jobs1". However, I want to copy all rows to an existing master sheet called "Weekly Jobs". Secondly, this is copying al the jobs based on a criteria, I want copy all jobs from Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and paste the link (to link the sheets) to Weekly jobs.

Basically, I want a code that could check if there are values in Monday sheet (from row 1 to row 98) and then copy all the rows with values to weekly jobs (link the two sheets). It should repeat this process for every day. It would be even better if the formatting gets copied over as well.

```
Public Sub CopyRows_ValuesAndNumberFormats()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xCWs As Worksheet
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xStrName As String
Dim xRStr As String
Dim xRRg As Range
Dim xC As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xStr = "Week Jobs1"
xRStr = "Completed"
Set xCWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(xStr)
If Not xCWs Is Nothing Then
    xCWs.Delete
End If
Set xCWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
xCWs.Name = xStr
xC = 3
For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Name <> xStr Then
        Set xRg = xWs.Range("I:I")
        Set xRg = Intersect(xRg, xWs.UsedRange)
        For Each xRRg In xRg
            If xRRg.Value = xRStr Then
               xRRg.EntireRow.Copy
               xCWs.Cells(xC, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
               xC = xC + 1
            End If
        Next xRRg
    End If
Next xWs
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might want to edit your tags... this is not (just) an HTML question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Edited the code in question.

```
Public Sub CopyRows_ValuesAndNumberFormats()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xCWs As Worksheet
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xC As Long
'On Error Resume Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xCWs = Sheets("Weekly Jobs")
xC = xCWs.Range("A" & xCWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Name <> xCWs.Name Then
        Set xRg = xWs.UsedRange
        xRg.EntireRow.Copy
        xCWs.Cells(xC, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        xC = xCWs.Range("A" & xCWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
Next xWs
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

And if there are other sheets than weekdays and "Weekly Jobs" then ...

```
Public Sub CopyRows_ValuesAndNumberFormats()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xCWs As Worksheet
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xC As Long, i As Long

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xCWs = Sheets("Weekly Jobs")
Dim sheetNames
sheetNames = Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")

xC = xCWs.Range("A" & xCWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWs = Sheets(sheetNames(i))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not xWs Is Nothing Then
        Set xRg = xWs.UsedRange
        xRg.EntireRow.Copy
        xCWs.Cells(xC, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        xC = xCWs.Range("A" & xCWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    Set xWs = Nothing
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```